# Scalability for Firebase Swift: Query vs Duplicate data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, scalability, firebase-realtime-database

I have posts that belong to groups. I'm considering two different approaches in terms of scalability:

**Method 1: Post with value of group accessed via query**

Structure:

```
{
 "posts": {
   "1": {
     "message": "hello world",
     "timeAdded": 1718281919,
     "posterId": 123,
     "group": 15
   },
  "2": {
    "message": "this is second"
    "timeAdded": 12717212182,
    "posterId": 124,
    "group": 3
   },
   ...
  }
}
```

Get a group's, i.e. group 15's, post through a query like:

```
ref.child("posts/group").queryEqualToValue("15").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in ... })
```

**Method 2: Duplicate data in group**

Structure:

```
{
 "posts": {
   "1": {
     "message": "hello world",
     "timeAdded": 1718281919,
     "posterId": 123,
     "group": 15
   },
  "2": {
    "message": "this is second"
    "timeAdded": 12717212182,
    "posterId": 124,
    "group": 3
   },
   ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "15": {
      "posts": {
        "1": {
          "message": "hello world",
          "timeAdded": 1718281919,
          "posterId": 123,
        },
       ...
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Get a group's, i.e. group 15's, post by simply:

```
ref.child("groups/15").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in ... })
```

Which is better design for scalability?

**EDIT:**

As a side question, is there a Firebase query that can query multiple values, not just one, i.e. return posts of not just group 15, but also 21, 28, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with Method 1? What doesn't it do? That method will handle thousands of posts and return any posts that belong to group 15 instantly. (I'm not saying it's the best, just curious as to what the issue is with it)

Comment: @Jay One of the key requirements I need, that I should have mentioned is that I will have to query for a few different groups at a time. Unless there is a queryEqualToValue("15,21,24") kind of query, I think adding 3 observes on the 3 groups 15, 21, 24 via Method 2 might be faster.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, but it will end up being a bit different than what you have. I'm pretty sure that the correct way to organize the data is to have both group and posts as different collections. In order to say that a post belongs to a given group however, just have the post's identifier in that group's 'posts' attribute.

```
{
 "posts": {
   "1": {
     "message": "hello world",
     "timeAdded": 1718281919,
     "posterId": 123,
     "group": 15
   },
   "2": {
    "message": "this is second"
    "timeAdded": 12717212182,
    "posterId": 124,
    "group": 3
   },
   ...
  },


  "groups": {
    "15": {
      "posts": {
        "1": true,
       }
       ...
      }
    } "3": {
      "posts" : {
         "2":true
       },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

This way, you can then get the post identifier and then use this to query Firebase to retrieve the information about that specific post.

This example is a bit confusing just because the identifiers for both the groups and the posts are low integer values :)

See the documentation from Firebase for more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#flatten_data_structures

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, that way I will have to make individual observeSingleEvent calls for each post identifier every time I fetch a group. 

Will it be more time-efficient (but less space-efficient) to just duplicate the whole post body inside posts of groups?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is absolute fastest way to do it, but since Firebase is implemented using web sockets, the time difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are querying the groups key a lot, you should make it a top level key:

```json
{
  "posts": {
    "15": {
      "1": {
        "message": "hello world",
        "timeAdded": 1718281919,
        "posterId": 123
      },
      "6": {
        "message": "another post",
        "timeAdded": 1718281919,
        "posterId": 122
      },
    },
    "3": {
      "2": {
        "message": "this is second"
        "timeAdded": 12717212182,
        "posterId": 124
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A structure like this allows you to fetch all the posts in group 15 by `/posts/15`

The examples in the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#flatten_data_structures), have a similar structure to your data with slightly different terms, 'chats' instead of 'groups' and 'messages' instead of 'posts'.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a need for the duplicate data in method 2 so I would suggest two solutions:

With the method 1 structure

```
postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("group").queryEqualToValue("15").observeEventType(.ChildAdded
postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("group").queryEqualToValue("15").observeEventType(.ChildChanged
postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("group").queryEqualToValue("15").observeEventType(.ChildRemoved    

postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("group").queryEqualToValue("21").observeEventType(.ChildAdded
postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("group").queryEqualToValue("21").observeEventType(.ChildChanged
postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("group").queryEqualToValue("21").observeEventType(.ChildRemoved

postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("group").queryEqualToValue("28").observeEventType(.ChildAdded
postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("group").queryEqualToValue("28").observeEventType(.ChildChanged
postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("group").queryEqualToValue("28").observeEventType(.ChildRemoved
```

This will set up observers on the postsRef watching for posts in groups 15, 21, and 28 for any new posts, changes to existing posts or removed posts.

Note that I am suggesting .ChildAdded, .ChildChanged and .ChildRemoved instead of .Value as .Value will return everything in the node with any change, which could be a lot of data.

Method 2 has duplicated data but there doesn't appear to be a need for it in this situation, so just keep the groups node

```
"groups": {
    "15": {
      "posts": {
        "1": {
          "message": "hello world",
          "timeAdded": 1718281919,
          "posterId": 123,
```

and add observers to the posts node within each

```
postsRef = groups/15/posts
   ...add observers like above
postsRef = groups/21/posts
   ...add observers like above
postsRef = groups/28/posts
   ...add observers like above
```

The down side of my suggestion #2 is queries as the structure is too deep to do much - but a need for a query wasn't specified in the question.

The first suggestion provides simplicity, denormalized data and the ability to query for anything. It's also fast and elastic.

As a side note, and this probably goes without saying, but please don't use integers - sequential or otherwise - as parent node names. Those should be obtained via childByAutoId.